# Alarm app with adjustable snooze

Tags: alarm-clock

I am very forgetful.  I use an automation app to set alarms for every meeting and reminder.  But I sometimes get alarms in the middle of something and need to snooze for a specific amount of time.

I am looking for an alarm app that has adjustable snooze times.  For example, when I press snooze I want to be able to set whether it snoozes for 1m, 2m, 5m, or 60m, etc.